# VBA - Running Total sum in dynamic range keeps disappearing

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

So I have 4 columns of values in a table, Income, Expenditure, AIncome and AExpenditure.

I'm trying to get a running total in the final column Total. This the formula I have so far, which works:

```
=SUM(INDEX([Income],1):[@Income],  INDEX([Expenditure],1):[@Expenditure], INDEX([AIncome],1):[@AIncome], INDEX([AExpenditure],1):[@AExpenditure])
```

My problem is that I don't know how to keep the sum in the Total column whenever I reload the table in Excel. The number of rows can vary from  1 to a few hundred.

Does anyone have any advice?

Thanks

---

An image of what the table looks like. THis is just a part with values in each column. J,K,L,M are Income, Expenditure, AIncome and AExpenditure. N is the total column. It's normally blank until I manually put in the formula.

#### Screenshot of part of the table

[image: Screenshot of part of the table]

I can reload this table to get different values from the query I'm using, but that's not important. the problem is when I fetch the query again, there's a new table, always the same amount of columns, but not the same amount of rows. And then I need to manually put in my formula again in the total column

Comment: Can you show some data as well please? I am unclear how this running total is working.

Comment: I'll try one second

Comment: This https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables helps with formatting data which you then paste between code tags. People can then copy your data. I should have said that first. I'm sorry.

Comment: I hope I've clarified both

Comment: And @QHarr no need to be sorry :)

Comment: What are you using to query? Normally, coordinates need to be designated when data is being imported, if this is the case, then (unless you are deleting values in N column) you should be able to set the range to A:M and set a formula in the N column. At that point, you can just tack an `=IF(SUM(A1:M1) <> 0, *original formula*, "")` statement. This would make the values appear blank when that row has no values.

Comment: Is it only the number of rows that changes?  Just find the last row with data and place the formula in the appropriate col / last row + 1.  Clear range, paste your table (recordset copy), find the last non blank row, place your formula.  If you need to find the column based on column header or last column that can also be done in addition to the row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would store the formula in a variable and after the query is loaded, copy the formula to the rows in the rnning total column.

Something like:

```
Const StoredFormula as string = "your formula"
Worksheets(x).range("range of the query table").formula = StoredFormula
```